# User Accounts in Win 7

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2008, sql-server

I am having a difficulty in Win 7 because of different accounts (Me the user account, and the admin account). Many times I have to close the program (Visual Studio, SQL Server) and restart again as admin. Is there any solution for merging these accounts? or my account convert to Admin? Came from XP OS so Win 7 seems a bit different in managing user accounts.

Any Help or suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For apps like Visual Studio or SSMS that need elevated rights just set them to always run as administrator rather than lowering overall machine security.

You can set it by right clicking the short cut and ticking the option on the Security bit of the tabs.

Comment: I've ticked Run this Program as an Admnistrator but now it always displays UAC elevation screen... How can I remove this elevated security screen

Comment: The only way to get rid of that is disable UAC for your account or start logging in with an administrator account.  Just keep in mind that either option brings with it increased risks.  The standard admin account is disabled but you can turn it back on: http://blog.eches.net/windows-7/how-to-enable-windows-7-hidden-administrator-account/

Answer (score 0):

If you are frequently using applications that require elevation (e.g. Visual Studio debugging web applications running under IIS, attaching to processes) then you may find running with UAC turned up and an administrator account is a better option that two separate accounts.

Of course with greater power comes greater responsibility.

Answer (score 0):

Could you alter the shortcuts to the applications that you would always like to run as administrator so that they always sign in as administrator? We have our Visual Studio 2008 configured to always run as administrator as it solves various issues.

Comment: but stil it shows the elevated screen with that dim background and "Do you want to allow xyz for changes".

Comment: Ah, sorry, have only just seen this response but it seems Chris W has answered this query already.